# IGrouping.ToList() - Handling null values

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, igrouping

I have a simple one-line linq query to find items in a list which contain the highest property value, and create a new list with them only if there are a certain count of items that match this criteria. For example:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>()
{
    new MyObject() { MyValue = 6 },
    new MyObject() { MyValue = 7 },
    new MyObject() { MyValue = 7 },
    new MyObject() { MyValue = 8 },
    new MyObject() { MyValue = 8 },
};

int countRequired = 2;

List<MyObject> highestValue2Required = objects.GroupBy( o => o.MyValue )
    .OrderByDescending( g => g.Key )
    .Where( g => g.Count() == countRequired )
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .ToList();
```

Providing there is data in my list that sattisfies these conditions, a new list will be created containing two instances of `MyObject`, the ones where `MyValue = 8`.

However, if there is no data matching the criteria, I hit an exception because the `IGrouping` result from the query is null, and calling `ToList()` on this doesnt work. For example:

```
int countRequired = 3;

List<MyObject> highestValue3Required = objects.GroupBy( o => o.MyValue )
    .OrderByDescending( g => g.Key )
    .Where( g => g.Count() == countRequired )
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .ToList();
```

Because there are only two instances of `MyObject` in the list where `MyValue` equals the highest value (which is 8), the query throws an exception

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
```

Is it possible to this null value in order to return an empty list within my "one line" query?

The obvious way to do this would be to remove the `ToList()` call and simply return an `IGrouping` result, and only call `ToList()` when it's not null, but I'm curious as to whether it can be done inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) after calling `FirstOrDefault()`. If this method returns `null`, the result of the entire expression will be null. You can then use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) to convert a `null` result to an empty list.

```
var highestValue3Required = objects.GroupBy( o => o.MyValue )
    .OrderByDescending( g => g.Key )
    .Where( g => g.Count() == countRequired )
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.ToList() ?? new List<MyObject>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and links to the relevant documentation. I'm familiar with the null coalescing operator, but not so much with the null conditional operator, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: It was null problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `.FirstOrDefault().ToList()`. Since `FirstOrDefault()` may return a value *or NULL*, you can't directly call `.ToList()`.

If you want the end result to be `null` if there are no matches, you can simply add a null conditioner (`?`) to the `FirstOrDefault()` call:

```
List<MyObject> highestValue2Required = objects.GroupBy(o => o.MyValue)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == countRequired)
    .FirstOrDefault()?
    .ToList();
```

If, however, you're not okay with a null value and you want to have an empty list instead, you can add the following extension method to your project in order to be able to use a one-liner:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return (source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }
}
```

Now, you can easily do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> highestValue2Required = objects.GroupBy(o => o.MyValue)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == countRequired)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .OrEmptyIfNull()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is great, but doesnt completely answer my question, as it returns a null value instead of an empty list. However,@Brett's answer does exactly that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Klicker I was adding a different solution to the answer already :) Glad you got the answer you were looking for anyway!

Comment: Just seen your edit. This looks like quite a handy generic extension method. Would I be right in thinking it'll act in the same way as a null conditional operator, but can be used by any IEnumerable collection?

Comment: @Klicker If you mean a null coalescing operator, then yes. It's a generic extension method for any `IEnumerable` source. I use it in most of my projects and it's very useful, indeed.